# Difference of Exponential Random Variables

Tags: probability

Your  Math  425  instructor  sends  you  a  lot  of  Canvas  announcements,  say  at  an  average  rate  of  one per  hour.   Incidentally,  that  is  also  the  average  rate  at  which  you  receive  updates  about  the  current pandemic.   If $X$ and $Y$ are  the  time  until  your  next  Math  425  announcement  and  until  your  next pandemic update respectively (which you both model as Exponential random variables with parameter 1), find the expected time between the next Canvas announcement and the next pandemic update.

I'm having trouble understanding why the following is not correct: $$E(Y-X) = E(Y)-E(X) = 0 $$
and $$E(X-Y)=E(X)-E(Y)=0$$ since they have the same distribution. Why can't you do this?

Comment: Is it because this can be rewritten as an absolute value?

Comment: Would make sense to compute $E|Y-X|$ instead, but the problem statement does not explicitly specify that absolute (positive) times should be considered. Maybe an omission?